# How to listen for .onUpdate changes for a map object using .before and .after firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using .onUpdate function with snap.before.data() and snap.after.data() with a map field value. The issue is that the changes trigger doesn't seem to be working. It's calling both strat and mark functions, when only one map object (mark) has been updated.

I know that .onUpdate does not trigger with a fieldvalue, but .before and .after changes of a field value can be compared. Can this work with a parent map/object? Both mark and strat maps have no parents in the doc.

```
export const BARupdate = functions.firestore
  .document('inputs/{inputUserID}')
  .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    functions.logger.log('bar update is running');

    // .after should represent after changes
    const userInfo: any = {
      ...snap.after.data(),
      userID: snap.after.id,
    };

   const newValue = snap.after.data();
   const oldValue = snap.before.data()
   
   if (userInfo['strat'] !== undefined) {
    if (newValue.strat !== oldValue.strat){
    console.log('snap same strat? NO') 
    const stratData = userBusinessInfo['strat'];
    const  userID = userBusinessInfo?.userID;
    } else {
      console.log('STRAT IS THE SAME')
    }
    return
   }

    if (userBusinessInfo['mark'] !== undefined) {
      if (newValue.mark !== oldValue?.mark){
        console.log('snap same mark? NO')
      const markData = userInfo['mark'];
      const userID = userInfo?.userID;
      } else {
        console.log('MARK IS THE SAME')
      }
      return
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it normal that `userBusinessInfo` isn’t defined? In addition what do you exactly mean by «  The issue is that the changes trigger doesn't seem to be working. » and « Both marketing and strategy maps have no parents in the doc »? Also what are the type of the `strat` and `mark` fields?

Comment: UserInfo is always defined but a map in userInfo can be undefined. The comparison of the .before and .after data is returning true when it is actually false. Strat and mark are both maps. The issue is that when mark is updated, strat return true that it was updated, even though it wasn't. I've included the data structure above.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a `users` collection and your CF is triggered for an `inputs` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the map objects may be returned with their properties in a different order.

Since you only have two properties by object, you can modify your code as follows:

```
    if (newValue.strat.id !== oldValue.strat.id || newValue.strat.name !== oldValue.strat.name) {
        console.log('snap same strat? NO')
        //...
    } else {
        console.log('STRAT IS THE SAME')
    }


    if (newValue.mark.id !== oldValue.mark.id || newValue.mark.name !== oldValue.mark.name) {
        console.log('snap same mark? NO')
        //...
    } else {
        console.log('MARK IS THE SAME')
    }
```

---

In  case the map objects are more complex, you should use another approach, e.g. using the [lodash library](https://lodash.com/), which performs a deep comparison between two values to check if they are equivalent with `_.isEqual(value1, value2)`.

See also: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+compare+two+objects